# MongoDB updating elements in array of objects from google functions

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-update

I have a collection for tracking some tasks performed by google functions

```
{
    _id: someid,
    tasks: [
        {
            taskId: "1",
            status: "PENDING"
        },
        {
            taskId: "2",
            status: "PENDING"
        }
    ]
}
```

Whenever a task completes, it updates its status by taskId to COMPLETE and this is working fine functionality wise.
The problem I'm facing is the number of tasks in `tasks` array can be in thousands, and at a point in time, there can be dozens of function instances trying to update the same document and it's causing high CPU usage. Is there a better way of modelling this collection for updates ?

Comment: According to the data you gave us, each task should be a document